# Can I do pointer arithmetic on an STL::vector::iterator

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Currently I use an iterator to search through a vector and test its elements. I access the elements using

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
if (*it == 0);
```

Can I use the same pointer arithmetic style logic to also test the next element (without altering my iterator)?

I first need to see if it will push the iterator out of bounds

```
if (it != myvec.end())
```

Then test both current element and next element

```
if (*it == 1 && *(it + 1) == 1)
```

Will this work as I expect from using pointers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the iterators for `std::vector` are [random access iterators](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/iterators#iterator_categories) so you add/subtract integral values to get other valid iterators.

Technically, it may not be pointer arithmetic, but they act just like pointers.

Comment: So, I can't do arithmetic operation on `list::iterator`, right?

Comment: @Alcott - correct. A list::iterator is a bidirectional iterator and does not support random access. You can use `std::advance` to do the move with a single call but complexity of advance is `O(n)` for lists (where it would be `O(1)` for a vector).

Answer (score 4):

This will work indeed as vector iterator are random access iterator. That is not only can you act on them like you would do with pointers, but they are pretty much implemented using pointers / pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if iterator is on the last element of the container then

```
*(it + 1)
```

has undefined behavior. 
You should check that

```
it + 1 != end
```

before dereferencing it.

Comment: So a bit like using pointers, you have to check yourself that it doesn't go out of bounds.